# How do I code against one github repo on 2 computers?

Tags: git, github

I have two computers from which I want to contribute to one github repo. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

To keep both repositories in sync you should to pull the latest changes to your machine whenever you start working on the code.

To do this you want to execute

```
git pull
```

...which is usually set up to pull from the default remote (origin) to your current branch. Git might complain if this isn't the case, and so the longer version will work as well:

```
git pull origin {branch_name}
```

*Note:* this is the same process that you would use if two or more people were working on the same repo. Which is essentially what is happening, instead of two different people working on the same repository, you have two different machines working on the same repository.

If you are starting out fresh on a new machine all you need to do is clone the repo to it first:

```
git clone {remote_url}
```

You get this url from your GitHub repo's home page. This command will make a complete working copy of the repo in a subdirectory.

Comment: lets say second computer has git set up. also has ssh keys for github. but does not have the github repo yet. then what should I do?  if i do: `git pull origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git` it does not work.

Comment: Yes you can either call `git init` and then the `git pull` you stated or you can use `git clone` both essentially will get you to the same spot. Just remember to setup your remote origin.  `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git` so that you have a place to push your changes to.

Comment: If you find this doesn't work double-check that you have set github to recognise your local key - something you might not have done on a new machine.

Answer (score 6):

You need to clone the repository on your second computer.

```
git clone git@github.com:myusername/myrepo.git
```

Now you can use `git pull` and `git push` to keep your local repository in sync with the one on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You want to checkout the repository on the other computer, you do not want to fork it.

Comment: you mean `clone` it? if I clone it then `git push origin master` does not work.

Comment: @Zandorf - It should. The point of `clone` is that it sets up a remote called "origin" to push to.

Comment: @Dan Ray - oh yeah now it does! So now if I go back to compuer 1. I have to do git pull now. works good!

Answer (score 0):

Starting working on another machine do the next:

1- Creat a new directory on your local machine to have your work saved to it.

2- from that newly created directory, open Bash( assuming that you already have git installed 
on your machine) by clicking the right mouse click and you will see (Git Bash here).

3- on Bash type git clone (your Repo URL OR ssh key). press enter

4- just done. :)