# Edit from PHPStorm purly from remote server

Tags: sublimetext2, development-environment, phpstorm, remote-server, coda

I am currently working with PHP/HTML on a remote server via PHPStorm. I love how intelligent it is, but i dont like how it forces me to have a local project and that i have to sync it. I work on the server from two different PC's and if i am going to download-upload everytime it is going to take a lot of time

Is it any way to work like in Coda2 and Sublime Text with pure remote access, but with the same intelligent system as PHPStorm has?

Comment: PhpStorm is meant to work with local files as it requires fast access to project files / source code. Even working over local network is not smooth in some cases. Of course, you could use some tools to mount remote file system into your local file system (so it looks like local for PhpStorm), but it will be SLOW (on project startup or when checking file system for external changes etc) + random freezes / delays out of nowhere could easily be happening.

Comment: The "two PCs" problem could be solved with a decent Version Control system, like Git. Even if you had to access the shared repo over the internet, it'll be faster than downloading the whole site because Git only transfers compressed deltas. Here's a good answer to get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012073/how-do-i-code-against-one-github-repo-on-2-computers . It's as simple as `git fetch` when you start working, then `git push` when you're done.